# Missing Properties Window

Tags: android

I have no idea where the properties window went. I have tried VIEW - Tool Windows - ... , but no properties option found!

Image of Design of XML file in Andriod Studio

[image: Image of Design of XML file in Andriod Studio]

Comment: Which properties? It seems perfect window